# In Windows cmd batch file how to ignore carriage return

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file, prompt

I have a Win 7 bat file that prompts user to enter a number, then it passes that number as an argument to a tcl script.

An optical barcode scanner is used to provide the number, but then I want user to be able to modify the number (using keyboard) before bat file continues. Problem is that the scanner seems to add a carriage return at the end of the scan which makes the bat file automatically continue (if I instead enter the number using keyboard instead of scanner, the bat file doesn't continue until keyboard Enter is pressed).

So I want the bat file to ignore the carriage return sent by the scanner, but then continue when the user hits the Enter on keyboard.

Here is my bat file:

```
echo off
set /p sernum= Enter the serial number:  
cd C:\Tcl\bin
tclsh.exe tcl_file.tcl %sernum%
cmd
```

Comment: Some scanners have the ability to send or not send a carriage return after the scan.  One option could be to look into the make/model of your scanner and see if you can disable the carriage return.

Comment: You might check here for some ideas as well not sure it they'd work or not but may be worth a try if it seems feasible to you for your need. http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2803

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I thought about it some more and realized I could modify the scanned input without requiring user to make changes via keyboard.

So here is my new bat script:

```
echo off
set /p sernum= Scan the serial number barcode label:  
REM extract last 6 chars from serial number & prepend text
set sernum=new_text%sernum:~-6%
cd C:\Tcl\bin
tclsh.exe tcl_file.tcl %sernum%
```

The "~-6" extracts out the last 6 chars from the scanned serial # (this is one of my requirements), and then I prepend some fixed text to it (another one of my requirements). Simple and easy.